# Create fortran function that can accept a scalar or an array

Tags: arrays, function, fortran, scalar

I am trying to write a function in fortran that takes two arguments, one of which will definitely be a 1-d array, but the other argument could be either an array or a scalar.  This is similar to what one can do with the `MIN` or `MAX` intrinsic fortran functions, which could compare either two arrays, or a scalar and an array (`MIN` or `MAX` could include more arguments, but I just need two).  I've been looking around online quite a bit but surprisingly I haven't found anything quite like this.  Is this possible to do in Fortran?  If I try to declare the incoming arguments with `dimension(:)` the compiler just expects them both to be 1-d arrays and it complains in case of a scalar argument.

Comment: How do you intend to use the argument which may be scalar or array? You can 'easily' create two functions, then use a generic so that the correct one is chosen when referenced, and you'll find many examples of that concept in questions and answers here. (But that may not be a suitable approach for you, which is why I ask for more detail on use.)

Comment: I actually want to wrap the min or max functions in some additional functions.  So ultimately it will be used inside a min or max function.  I think the answer below may be enough to help me do this.

Comment: `min` and `max` are somewhat special functions that a user simply cannot implement in standard Fortran.  These function can take an arbitrary number of arguments.  A user cannot write a variadic function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by writing an generic interface that encapsulates the two functions.  Here's an example

```
module foo

  implicit none    ! Never write a module without this statement

  private          ! Never write a module without this statement

  public fcn       ! Make the generic function fcn public

  interface fcn    ! Define generic function
     module procedure bar
     module procedure bah
  end interface fcn

  contains
     ! Function accepts an array and a scalar
     function bar(a,b) result(res)
        integer res
        integer, intent(in) :: a(:)
        integer, intent(in) :: b
        res = sum(a * b)
     end function bar
     ! Function accepts to arrays
     function bah(a,b) result(res)
        integer res
        integer, intent(in) :: a(:)
        integer, intent(in) :: b(:)
        res = sum(a * b)
     end function bah
end module foo

program testing
  use foo
  implicit none
  integer i(4), j(4), k
  i = [1, 2, 3, 4]
  j = [10, 20, 30, 40]
  k = 10
  print *, fcn(i,k)
  print *, fcn(i,j)
end program testing
```