# Fortran function accepts scalar or vector

Tags: types, fortran

I'm writing a Fortran function with input parameters that can be either scalars or vectors. But Fortran doesn't like the `if-else` statements to declare the parameters:

```
program sinwave

    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: N = 100
    real, dimension (N) :: x, t
    real :: x0, t0
    integer :: i

    x = (/ (((i-1)*0.12)+1, i=1,N,1) /)
    t = (/ (((i-1)*0.05)+0.2, i=1,N,1) /)
    print *, test(x,t,N)
    x0 = x(N-14)
    t0 = t(N-14)
    print *, test(x0,t0,1)

contains

    function test(x,t,xlen) result(y)
        implicit none
        integer :: xlen
        if (xlen==1) then
            real :: x, y, t
        elseif (xlen>1) then
            real, dimension (xlen,1) :: x, y, t
        end if
        y = sin(x+0.1*t)
    end function test

end program sinwave
```

Is there a more elegant way to do it aside from [writing one function for scalar inputs and another function for vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64995753/3084842)?

Comment: Make test "elemental"?

Comment: Tale a look at `Elemental` functions

Comment: Rather excitingly, the assignment of the result `y = sin(x+0.1*t)` takes precise advantage of `sin` being an elemental function, accepting either a scalar or array of any shape.